# Runtime design - storing and loading form layout (recursively?)

Tags: delphi, persistence, tpersistent

I'm creating an application which layout needs to be fully configurable on client-side. It means each component (control) can be resized and moved around the form, new controls can be added, or some removed. 
I'd like to use JVCL Runtime Design (Design Surface and Object Inspector).

The problem is about **storing** and **loading** the form.
TStream.**WriteComponent** method doesn't support recursive writing, which means it saves just the "first level" of components.

So, by example, if I put a TPanel on a Form, then TButton on the Panel, and call WriteComponent on a Form, only TPanel will be saved, not the TButton.

My question is - *how do I use **WriteComponent** to store ***full*** control hierarchy?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should make the form the *Owner* of all components even if the *Parent* is different. Regarding your example, the button and the panel should both be owned by the form.

Comment: thank you. I thought "ownership" hierarchy is supposed to follow "parentship"